# .NET Core high memory usage in Docker (AWS ECS Fargate)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, amazon-ecs, hangfire

Here is a description of the application.  I have a console application that runs Hangfire.  There are several jobs that are recurring.  One job, in particular, parses several large XML files.  I deploy this console app as an AWS ECS Fargate ontainer.

Every time the recurring job runs, the container memory usage keeps rising and rising until either the application becomes unresponsive or AWS kills the container.  This is a 16GB container on ECS (big) and so it should be able to handle anything I throw at it.  I can tell as soon as the memory usage gets up toward ~13GB it is doomed.

The kicker is that I run this application locally and it never gets very high in memory usage.  I will post a couple of example logs from both my workstation and on the container below.

THANKS FOR ANY INSIGHT!

Parsing the XML:

- Use XmlSerializer to drop into a JSON formatted object
- Use XDocument to just go through the document
- Use XSD file to generate classes, and then XmlSerializer to populate

All three work locally, but use a ton of memory on the server.  These are unchanging XML files, and I run the exact same files on both local and in the container.

FYI:  I have turned off server garbage collection on the container.  That didn't work.

**EDIT 3/5/2019**

The logs below are from the following code.  It doesn't have the full breath of the application which is quite complex.  This code is in a method registered with Hangfire to run once per day.  It pulls XML files from an FTP site, and then runs essentially the code below to process those files.  Each file is at most 10 MB in size.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(Model);
foreach (var file in files)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Processing file: {file.Name}");
    Model model;
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(file.FullName, new XmlReaderSettings { CheckCharacters = false }))
    {
        model = (Model)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
    SaveToDatabase(model);
    Console.WriteLine($"Application Memory Usage - Working: {Process.GetCurrentProcess()?.WorkingSet64 ?? 0}, Private: {Process.GetCurrentProcess()?.PrivateMemorySize64 ?? 0}");
}
```

Workstation log:

```
[13:52:58 INF] Processing file: price_feed_supplemental_002981.xml
[13:52:58 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 1.4 GB, Private: 1.6 GB
[13:52:58 INF] Processing file: price_feed_002982.xml
[13:53:01 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 1.4 GB, Private: 1.6 GB
[13:53:01 INF] Processing file: price_feed_supplemental_002982.xml
[13:53:01 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 1.4 GB, Private: 1.6 GB
[13:53:01 INF] Processing file: price_feed_002983.xml
[13:53:01 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 1.4 GB, Private: 1.6 GB
[13:53:01 INF] Processing file: price_feed_supplemental_002983.xml
[13:53:02 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 1.4 GB, Private: 1.6 GB
[13:53:02 INF] Processing file: price_feed_002984.xml
```

Container log:

```
[19:05:35 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 1.9 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:05:35 INF] Processing file: price_feed_supplemental_002987.xml
[19:05:35 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 1.9 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:05:35 INF] Processing file: price_feed_supplemental_002988.xml
[19:05:35 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 1.9 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:05:35 INF] Processing file: price_feed_002988.xml
[19:05:40 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 1.9 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:05:40 INF] Processing file: price_feed_002989.xml
[19:05:43 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 2.1 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:05:43 INF] Processing file: price_feed_supplemental_002989.xml
[19:05:43 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 2.1 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:05:43 INF] Processing file: price_feed_supplemental_002990.xml
[19:05:43 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 2.1 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:05:43 INF] Processing file: price_feed_002990.xml
[19:05:51 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 2.6 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:05:51 INF] Processing file: price_feed_002991.xml
[19:05:57 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 2.2 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:05:57 INF] Processing file: price_feed_supplemental_002991.xml
[19:06:00 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 2.2 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:06:00 INF] Processing file: price_feed_002992.xml
[19:06:19 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 2.1 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:06:19 INF] Processing file: price_feed_supplemental_002992.xml
[19:06:21 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 2.3 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:06:21 INF] Uncompressing file: usa_LTSF_20190228_002993_001_INC.zip
[19:06:22 INF] Source file: price_feed_002993_1.xml
[19:06:22 INF] Source file: price_feed_supplemental_002993_8.xml
[19:06:23 INF] Source file: price_feed_supplemental_002993_11.xml
[19:06:23 INF] Source file: price_feed_002993_2.xml
[19:06:23 INF] Source file: price_feed_supplemental_002993_5.xml
[19:06:23 INF] Source file: price_feed_supplemental_002993_4.xml
[19:06:24 INF] Source file: price_feed_supplemental_002993_17.xml
[19:06:24 INF] Source file: price_feed_supplemental_002993_15.xml
[19:06:24 INF] Source file: price_feed_supplemental_002993_3.xml
[19:06:25 INF] Source file: price_feed_supplemental_002993_1.xml
[19:06:25 INF] Source file: price_feed_supplemental_002993_9.xml
[19:06:25 INF] Source file: price_feed_supplemental_002993_7.xml
[19:06:26 INF] Source file: price_feed_supplemental_002993_6.xml
[19:06:26 INF] Source file: price_feed_supplemental_002993_14.xml
[19:06:26 INF] Source file: price_feed_supplemental_002993_13.xml
[19:06:27 INF] Source file: price_feed_supplemental_002993_16.xml
[19:06:27 INF] Source file: price_feed_supplemental_002993_12.xml
[19:06:27 INF] Source file: price_feed_supplemental_002993_2.xml
[19:06:28 INF] Source file: price_feed_supplemental_002993_10.xml
[19:06:28 INF] Processing file: price_feed_002984.xml
[19:06:28 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 2.5 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:06:28 INF] Processing file: price_feed_supplemental_002984.xml
[19:06:28 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 2.5 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:06:28 INF] Processing file: price_feed_supplemental_002985.xml
[19:06:28 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 2.5 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:06:28 INF] Processing file: price_feed_002985.xml
[19:06:28 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 2.5 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:06:28 INF] Processing file: price_feed_supplemental_002986.xml
[19:06:28 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 2.5 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:06:28 INF] Processing file: price_feed_002986.xml
[19:06:28 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 2.5 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:06:28 INF] Processing file: price_feed_002987.xml
[19:06:30 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 2.6 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:06:30 INF] Processing file: price_feed_supplemental_002987.xml
[19:06:30 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 2.6 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:06:30 INF] Processing file: price_feed_supplemental_002988.xml
[19:06:30 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 2.6 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:06:30 INF] Processing file: price_feed_002988.xml
[19:06:35 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 2.9 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:06:35 INF] Processing file: price_feed_002989.xml
[19:06:38 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 3.1 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:06:38 INF] Processing file: price_feed_supplemental_002989.xml
[19:06:38 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 3.1 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:06:38 INF] Processing file: price_feed_supplemental_002990.xml
[19:06:38 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 3.1 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:06:38 INF] Processing file: price_feed_002990.xml
[19:06:47 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 3.7 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:06:47 INF] Processing file: price_feed_002991.xml
[19:06:53 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 4.1 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:06:53 INF] Processing file: price_feed_supplemental_002991.xml
[19:06:55 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 4.3 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:06:55 INF] Processing file: price_feed_002992.xml
[19:07:05 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 4.9 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:07:05 INF] Processing file: price_feed_supplemental_002992.xml
[19:07:07 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 5.0 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:07:07 INF] Processing file: price_feed_002993_1.xml
[19:09:40 INF] 1 servers were removed due to timeout
[19:10:49 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 10.0 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:10:49 INF] Processing file: price_feed_supplemental_002993_8.xml
[19:12:10 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 12.5 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:12:10 INF] Processing file: price_feed_supplemental_002993_11.xml
[19:13:08 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 13.5 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:13:08 INF] Processing file: price_feed_002993_2.xml
[19:14:06 INF] Application Memory Usage - Working: 13.8 GB, Private: 0.0 bytes
[19:14:06 INF] Processing file: price_feed_supplemental_002993_5.xml
```

Comment: If you process ALL the log files on your local box, what happens to the memory? The stats for your local box only shows up to `002984.xml` and memory prior to that stays constant. On your server, you have a couple of files where the memory stays constant too.

Comment: I didn’t include all the local logs as they are the exact memory usage for all of them. This was run locally and through the debugger of Visual Studio with the same results.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is related to a [blog post by Maoni](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/maoni/2018/11/16/running-with-server-gc-in-a-small-container-scenario-part-0/) about an issue Nick was having. The high core count of the machine the container is running on may be causing the heap to grow to a large amount before GC happens. Can you check if it's a case of the GC not running vs. a memory leak by calling `GC.Collect` periodically?

Comment: Can you also share what version of the runtime this is, etc.

Comment: @JohnD This is running under .NET Core 2.2.

Comment: The XML parsing code actually matters a lot. Even in the full framework, creating the XmlSerializer one way would cache one instance per type. Another way would create a *new* serializer every time, resulting in delays and huge memory usage. Strings are immutable too so string manipulation results in a *lot* of temporary objects. Finally, XmlSerializer is kind-of-neglected in .NET Core, so it definitely doesn't have the new Span<T> optimizations.

Comment: How did you test the code locally? How often was the GC invoked? Did you profile the code, or at least check the memory usage in the Diagnostics Windows while testing? It could be that the GC on the container runs infrequently so it doesn't clear ghost/temporary objects

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for responding.  Do you have any docs on the various ways to create the XmlSerializer?  Basically, it is getting created once per run, and then re-used for each file being processed.  I ran through VS and garbage collection was probably hitting once every file or so.  I ran the application through command line as well (which to me should be the closest match to the server running the app) and that represents the logs I posted.

Comment: There are a lot of articles. The behaviour is described in [Dynamically generated assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.7.2#dynamically-generated-assemblies). It's also possible to pregenerate the assemblies with the [XML Serializer generator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.XmlSerializer.Generator). The docs don't keep pace that well with the code though.

Comment: Post your code though. There could be other things that generated a lot of temporary strings and fail to release them. Your code may be holding on to the deserialized objects for example. Perhaps there's a reference to the root object somewhere. You may be processing too many objects concurrently, preventing the GC from running *especially* if you've disabled server GC

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the interesting thing to me is that the same code is acting differently in two systems.  Not calling the XmlSerializer a red herring, but I re-wrote the code to not use XmlSerializer with the same results.  I am wondering if the fact that in the Docker container there is no allocated PrivateMemorySize64 as compared to the local run has something to do with it.  Is a docker-based app not able to swap memory and because of that it has to put everything in active memory?  I am spitballing here.

Comment: Actually... looks like the PrivateMemorySize64 might not be working right on linux (docker) based systems.  https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23449

Comment: Post the code please. `with the same results` probably means that the deserialized objects are kept alive. High memory usage is a *symptom*. The cause is creating more objects than necessary and keeping them around for longer. I've run in similar problems with other parsers too. Big objects go to the LOB cache and live longer. Explicitly clearing temporary objects/collections helps.  Using SAX-like or listener APIs also helps. If you *don't* load 10MB worth of objects, you won't have to dispose them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189458/discussion-between-trey-gourley-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 1):

Disabling Server Garbage Collection (forcing Workstation Garbage Collection) by adding `<ServerGarbageCollection>false</ServerGarbageCollection>` to the web app's csproj file seemed to make the GC more *eager* and so that helped keep the heap small, but unmanaged memory was still creeping up slowly. It ended up being a memory leak- a static method was passing one of its arguments by reference back to the caller, static methods aren't managed by GC sooo each time this method was called and given more strings to enumerate, that object passed by reference got larger and larger.

I removed the pass-by-reference and the method is now returning the object normally (via `return`) but I still had to call `GC.Collect()` in this static method to prevent momentary spikes of around 500MB-1GB. Normally this might be alright even in a production environment because GC does quickly bring memory usage back down to normal levels, however just one of these memory spikes **will** kill the ECS instance if it causes the .NET app to exceed the memory quota.

Needless to say, we are working with some large strings in O(N^2) enumerations and I suspect the call to `GC.Collect()` can be removed after a good rewrite of this method. In your case, you might be missing a `using` somewhere, or you're using events (unlikely), or maybe like me you have a static method passing something by reference- or not- and that static method, exempt from GC, is slowly leaking.

As for disabled "Server" garbage collection, this seems to be effective only because the Fargate/ECS task is running on one vCPU only. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/workstation-server-gc) for more info on Server vs Workstation GC.

Visual Studio 2022's built-in performance measurement tools are okay, but VS would occasionally crash (my work computer is also weak as hell) so I ended up using Jetbrains' dotMemory, which has a nicer interface and better snapshot comparison functionality.