# Dotnetcore 3.1 memory allocation in Docker

Tags: docker, memory, .net-core, cgroups

I'm running a dotnetcore 3.1 application in a Docker container (in Kubernetes cluster).

First case :
I run the application with the following Docker/Kubernetes limits : `requests.memory: 300Mi, limits.memory: 500Mi`. According to my monitoring, the application consumes 250Mi and it seems slow.

Second case :
I run the application with the following Docker/Kubernetes limits : `requests.memory: 500Mi, limits.memory: 700Mi`. According to my monitoring, the application consumes 450Mi and it seems more fast.

In each case, the application is never OMMKilled, and seems limited by `requests.memory`. I know Dotnetcore 3.1 uses cgroups, so I suppose it allows more or less memory usage in function of cgroups. But how it really works ? Why is it based on `requests` and not on `limits` ? How do I know what requests/limits my application really needs ?

Comment: If you have less memory, the GC will have to run more often to collect garbage. Which means you should find *why* there's so much garbage. The application will run a lot faster if you reduce string allocations, or inefficient list operations,  no matter the memory.

Comment: Each string operation creates a new temporary string, which has to be GC'd. *Avoiding* string operations can increase performance tremendously. Adding items to a list leads to the reallocation of the list's internal buffer. Adding a `capacity` with even an approximation of the expected items will also increase performance by avoiding copying and GC'ing the old buffers.

Comment: Using spans instead of string to find substrings, splitting, trimming etc will reduce temporary strings.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post. The resources limits are Docker/Kubernetes limits. I was talking about the Dotnetcore 3.1 memory consumption IN a Docker container. How it works ?

Comment: I've found answer to this question in another comment. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54992771/net-core-high-memory-usage-in-docker-aws-ecs-fargate#comment96745526_54992771